# NSURL Error code extraction

Tags: ios, xcode, error-handling, nsurl

I try to do my  `NSURL` error-handling and have a little problem. 
When i'm getting an error i want to handle it different for different error-codes.

In my case i want to check if the error that i'm getting is the one with errorcode 1005.

**This is what I get when I print as follows:**

```
NSLog(@"%@",error);

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)" UserInfo=0x1700ff000 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=MyURL, NSErrorFailingURLKey=MyURL, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData=<CFData 0x17025a580 [0x1936b2c80]>{length = 3640, capacity = 4096, bytes = 0x3c3f786d6c2076657273696f6e3d2231 ... 2f706c6973743e0a}, NSUnderlyingError=0x17025cf80 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1005.)"}
```

**and this is what I want to extract from it:**
*-1005*

I already searched for it and found a solution which doesn't work. (I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS) 
**NSLog(@"%@", [error code]);**

**Afterwards I want to compare it similar to:**

```
if(error.code == -1005){
//handle error
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [error code]);
```

Because `code` is `NSInteger`. Use:

```
NSLog(@"%d", [error code]);
```

Refer: [NSError Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSError/code) for more details